# How to remove specific string occurences from file?

Tags: bash, sed

Before this question is marked as a duplicate let me explain. I'm trying to remove the following string occurrences from a file:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

i've looked at similar questions and they suggest the usage of the sed command:

```
sed -i -e 's/removedString//g' filename
```

The problem is that when I execute the above command with the string:

```
sed -i -e 's/ * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)//' filename
```

I get the following error:

> sed: -and expression # 1, character 24: the numeric numeric for the `s' command can not be zero (s /// 0)

I'm assuming that the `s/` only applies to strings and not numbers, is there a way to correctly remove this painful string?

Comment: You need to escape special characters like `*`, `/` and `.`.

Comment: And how is this Python-related?

Comment: My mistake, putting python there was automatic lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e 's| \* Running on http://0\.0\.0\.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)||' filename
```

And usually when you are toying with this, don't add `-i` yet, so just:

```
sed -e 's| \* Running on http://0\.0\.0\.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)||' filename
```

When it's working, then add the `-i` to change file(s) **i**nplace.

The mechanism is **s**ubstitute by `regex`.
And many characters have special meanings in `regex` so you have to escape it.
The character after `s` will act as the separator, `s#From#to#` like this.
And you might want to add `g` flag to replace multiple occurances. `s$from$to$g` or so.

And in your case there're many `/` so might as well change it to another, `|` in above examples.

Comment: Was just about to post this. Use a different separator from `/`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29966789/3220769)

Comment: That's the right thing to do in this case; instead of escaping everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a different separator (instead of "/"), you don't have to escape everything:

```
sed -e 's| * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)||g' <filename>
```

Comment: Well, you still have to escape `*` and `.` to be exact though ;-)

Comment: I've already tested this command, and it worked without problems. :D